# URL.createObjectURL(blob);

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser, blob

I am creating a PDF and opening in a new browser. My issue is word 'blob:' is getting appended to the URL

blob:http://localhost:3000/a0b859c9-57a0-40b7-a60f-9d2a72ab3c14

and I would like to be 'http://localhost:3000/a0b859c9-57a0-40b7-a60f-9d2a72ab3c14'

Is there a way I could achieve this ? My code is below

```
 const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type : 'application/pdf'});
 var pdfFileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 window.open(pdfFileUrl);
 URL.revokeObjectURL(pdfFileUrl);


update:
I tried below code as well. It also gives the same results.

''
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Send the proper header information along with the request


    // listen for `onload` event
    xhr.onload = () => {
        // process response
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            // parse JSON data
           // console.log( "Response Received")
           // var pdfurl = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response) ;
           console.log(xhr.response)
           window.open(URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response));

        
        } else {
            console.log(" In Error block")
            console.error('Error!');
        }
    };
    
    // create a `GET` request
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob'
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    // send request
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));''
```

Comment: `blob:` at the beginning of a URL means that the URL is an Object URL... So, unless you have a file saved with that crazy URL, that won't work like you think. What is `response.data`? The PDF?... Then, as long as you have your `xhr.responseType = 'blob';`, you should be able to do like `xhr.onload = function(){ open(URL.createObjectURL(this.response)); }`.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that as well. It also appends the url with blob.   xhr.onload = () => {
        // process response
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            // parse JSON data
           // console.log( "Response Received")
           // var pdfurl = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response) ;
           console.log(xhr.response)
           window.open(URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response));
Result: blob:http://localhost:3000/ab21216e-26f2-498e-83d6-4f5edc2dc358